# iOS SDK 7.1 with iOS 8.1 generating slow behaviours

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sdk, ios8

I'm actually building an app with the SDK 7.1 while running on a 8.1 environnement. It works fine except when I'm loading a view contening a scrollView with a lot of elements, which cause to take a long time before the view with the scrollView can finally appears. The more elements on the scrollView, the longest is the time I have to wait before it appears.
I can't post any code here because I can't find where the problem is but it seems to happen  between the viewWillAppear and the viewDidAppear of the view with the scrollView.

FYI, my scrollView display custom uibuttons with images inside (no text).

Also, I tried to compile with the SDK 8.1 while running on iOS 7.1 and it worked fine.

I know it's not very precise but maybe I missed something really important with iOS 8.1

Any guess ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to profile it in tools and see where is majority of the time is spent.

Comment: I just tried to do it with the time profiler in Instruments and guess what, no problem at all, It worked with the good speed. Of course It re-became slow when I don't profile the app. It's lovely

Comment: Try to record time stamps using NSLog. Good places to insert it will be viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, didLayoutSubviews methods.

Comment: Sounds great but what's the aim of this ?

Comment: To see where the time is spent.

Comment: Ok ok my bad. I'll try between more methods but I already knew the time was spent between the viewWillAppear and the viewDidAppear that's why. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Then it's related to the layout. You might want to check with NSLogs how many times layout is called and check if it's really necessary